# Analysis of Pre-post Likert-type scales: Intervention vs. Control group

Tags: methodology, method-comparison, case-control-study, intervention-analysis

I gathered the following data:

- **Intervention group** (n= 24, received treatment): **pre- and post- scores** of different psychometric questionnaires
- **Control group** (n=23, inactive): same questionnaires, same time, **pre- and post scores**

The intervention and the control group are matched 1:1 by the main variable of interest (work type), except for one missing control (I guess I'll have to do the analysis on n=23).

Research question: **was the intervention effective in improving the scores on the questionnaires?**

We previously did the same intervention without a control group, and I used the Wilcoxon signed-rank test to compare the results of the questionnaires pre- and post- intervention.

Now with a control group and a beginner's experience with statistical methods, I'm not sure how to analyze the data.

How should I go about it?